# Causal Impact Summary - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python, nonetype

anyone can help?
Here are my codes.

```
df_ci = pd.DataFrame(df_ig.groupby(['Tanggal'])['INTERACTIONS IG'].sum())
df_ci
```

It is what the dataframe looks like.

INTERACTIONS IG

Tanggal

2021-12-02  74.0

2021-12-03  326.0

2021-12-14  51.0

... ...

2022-05-30  80.0

2022-05-31  270.0

Then, i used Causal Impact packages.

```
pre = ['2021-12-02', '2022-02-28']  
post = ['2022-03-01', '2022-05-31'] 
from causalimpact import CausalImpact
ci = CausalImpact(df_ci["INTERACTIONS IG"], pre, post)
ci.summary()
```

When i wanted to show the summary, plot, and inferences of Causal Impact, it got an error:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\causalimpact\analysis.py in summary(self, output, width, path)
    727         confidence = "{}%".format(int((1 - alpha) * 100))
    728         post_period = self.params["post_period"]
--> 729         post_inf = self.inferences.loc[post_period[0] : post_period[1], :]
    730         post_point_resp = post_inf.loc[:, "response"]
    731         post_point_pred = post_inf.loc[:, "point_pred"]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Call `ci.run()` before `ci.summary()`.

```py
ci = CausalImpact(df_ci["INTERACTIONS IG"], pre, post)
ci.run()  # Add this
ci.summary()
```